# calling java function (retrieving java data) from javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I want to invoke function in java from javascript and that function return data(value) to javascript.
Basically I want javaScript to communicate with simple java structure program not the java applet .like

```
import something.....;
import something1....;

public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ...
        function 1;
        function 2;
        ...
    }
}
```

suppose the above is my java program . I don't want java to call java applet but the simple java program

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html) might be helpful.

Comment: you should just use a size 0 applet. i cannot thing of another way.

Comment: If you don't want to use applet you should create a http service which takes in the required input and produces the required output and the end point of that service will be called by your javascript code.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm should help you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to invoke javascript in java.  My best suggestion would be use a jsf or anything you can use for ui (e.g html, jsp) so that you can pass the value from javascript to java through it.